# Use Navigation View Controller for navigation between Subviews

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, addsubview

I have a MainViewController which cover's whole screen on iPad and i have three subviews each having frame = (0,0,1024,150)
The required config of subviews and segue between them is being done in storyboard.
I want to present subviews on top of the screen using navigationViewController...
i am using this code to do it.....

```
UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
nvc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 150);
[self.view addSubview:nvc.view];
```

myViewController is the initial view i want to have in navigation view

code is working fine only problem i have is the views not coming in their frame size. They coming in full screen (1024/768).

What i can do to maintain subviews size ?